# Rails 6 app not validating belongs_to associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails engine which encapsulates a piece of my application's funtionality. I have a bunch of models in the engine, which have various belongs_to associations defined. As of rails 5 these associations are supposed to be required by default, unless `optional: true` is specified in the definition.

I’m still able to create instances of the models without any validation errors. I haven’t specified `optional: true` on any of the associations, nor is the config option`config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default` set anywhere. Besides, it was removed in rails 6 anyway.

I can't think of any reason the model instances would not fail validation. I would expect any instances of any model with an undefined belongs_to association would be invalid and raise an error. Why would these records pass validation?

Comment: Looking at the source...https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/18707ab17fa492eb25ad2e8f9818a320dc20b823/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/belongs_to.rb.  It seems the will only happen if model.belongs_to_required_by_default is set to false, or required is set to false.

Comment: @dbugger Ok that's interesting - I set a breakpoint in that file and it looks like `required` is set on line 118: `required = model.belongs_to_required_by_default` but, `belongs_to_required_by_default` is just nil; it's not set anywhere in my app, and the only place I can see it being set is here https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/18707ab17fa492eb25ad2e8f9818a320dc20b823/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb line 91. That line is inside a block that only runs if target_version is 5.0. I don't see how belongs_to required could be the default behavior if the value is never set.

Comment: All the cases >= 5.1 include a line such as `load_defaults "5.0"`, so the default is also set for rails 6. See also https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#results-of-config-load-defaults, where it says "Such that passing, say, 6.0 also gets the new defaults from every version before it." and there's only the `default = true` from 5.0

Comment: @MatthiasWinkelmann thanks for pointing that out, it makes sense of the question I had earlier.

Comment: You can always check this in your console. see what's returned `Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default`

Comment: @DeepakMahakale - thanks! I can now see that the value is set to nil in the rails console for my engine. When I look in the console for another engine (one that is behaving as expected) it shows that the value is true. Since the value is not being set anywhere in my engine, maybe one of the gem dependencies is doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem, thanks to @MatthiasWinkelmann for the tip. It turns out my engine was not calling `load_defaults` at all. I needed to add the following to spec/dummy/config/application.rb:

```
module Dummy
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults Rails::VERSION::STRING.to_f

    ... etc ....
  end
end
```

here is an article containing more explanation:
[An upgraded Rails gem does not upgrade your Rails configuration](https://www.codementor.io/@help/an-upgraded-rails-gem-does-not-upgrade-your-rails-configuration-fft2ewe5r)

I probably would have done better to mention in my question that I'm in the process of upgrading my application from Rails 4.2 to 6.1. The change was introduced in Rails 5.